# ParseUser and ParseObject in threads cause ANR

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parse-platform

I'm having an issue with my Android application. When the application tries to save a ParseObject sometimes it blocks UI and generates ANR. According to the generated traces.txt, only one of the method I've written is involved, that is saveClimbing. This method simply calls onSaveBackground on a ParseObject:

```
public static void saveClimbing(final ParseObject p_climbing, final Climbing l_climbing){
p_climbing.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {    
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException ex) {
                    if(ex == null){
                        //no problems
                        l_climbing.setSaved(true);
                        ClimbApplication.climbingDao.update(l_climbing);
                        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Climbing correctly saved in Parse");
                    }else{
                        l_climbing.setSaved(false);
                        ClimbApplication.climbingDao.update(l_climbing);
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            }); 
}
```

The other involved method is ParseUser.saveCurrentUserAsync and it causes starvation, but I cannot understand when it is called and it is causing this. Am I doing something wrong?

This is the first part of the traces.txt:

```
JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=180 (plus 1 weak)

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 MONITOR
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41700578 self=0x4009c120
  | sysTid=26943 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074999292
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=3698 stm=442 core=0
  at com.parse.ParseUser.getSessionToken(ParseUser.java:~439)
  - waiting to lock <0x41fec980> (a java.lang.Object) held by tid=21         (Task.BACKGROUND_EXECUTOR-thread-47)
  at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentSessionToken(ParseUser.java:963)
  at com.parse.ParseObject.saveAsync(ParseObject.java:1348)
  at com.parse.ParseObject$9.then(ParseObject.java:1337)
  at com.parse.ParseObject$9.then(ParseObject.java:1333)
  at com.parse.TaskQueue.enqueue(TaskQueue.java:58)
  at com.parse.ParseObject.saveAsync(ParseObject.java:1333)
  at com.parse.ParseObject.saveInBackground(ParseObject.java:1424)
  at org.unipd.nbeghin.climbtheworld.util.ParseUtils.saveClimbing(ParseUtils.java:40)
  at org.unipd.nbeghin.climbtheworld.ClimbActivity$8.done(ClimbActivity.java:1422)
  at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
  at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
  at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:917)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Task.BACKGROUND_EXECUTOR-thread-47" prio=5 tid=21 MONITOR
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4364af68 self=0x5b3d9cd0
  | sysTid=28045 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1597635584
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at com.parse.ParseUser.saveCurrentUserAsync(ParseUser.java:~971)
  - waiting to lock <0x41fd7df8> (a java.lang.Object) held by tid=1 (main)
  at com.parse.ParseUser.access$000(ParseUser.java:20)
  at com.parse.ParseUser$1.then(ParseUser.java:476)
  at com.parse.ParseUser$1.then(ParseUser.java:469)
  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:353)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:364)
  at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:410)
  at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:402)
  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
  at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
  at com.parse.Task.access$300(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:311)
  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:308)
  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
  at com.parse.Task.access$300(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:311)
  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:308)
  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
  at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
  at com.parse.ParseRequest$4.then(ParseRequest.java:324)
  at com.parse.ParseRequest$4.then(ParseRequest.java:316)
  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
  at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
  at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
  at com.parse.Task.access$300(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:311)
  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:308)
  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
  at com.parse.Task.access$300(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:311)
  at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:308)
  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
  at com.parse.Task.access$400(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:346)
  at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:343)
  at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:510)
  at com.parse.Task.access$800(Task.java:22)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:565)
  at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:599)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:493)
  at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:485)
  at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
  at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
  at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
  at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
  at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:485)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**EDIT**: in the meantime I'm also saving a ParseUser object with saveInBackground method in another part of my code. It seems that the ANR is caused while the saveInBackground of the ParseUser object is executing and the saveInBackground called by saveClimbing tries to execute. The ANR happens only sometimes, not at every execution. Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: this seems to be a bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/591538734311827/). I'm going to try the new android Parse SDK to see if the deadlock disappears.

Comment: Could it be `ClimbApplication.climbingDao.update(l_climbing);` that's causing the ANR?

Comment: @Barend According to the traces.txt the p_climbing.saveInBackground is causing the ANR...but it doesn't cause ANR all the times it executes...the thing I can't understand is what causes saveCurrentUserSync to start and to let the ANR happen

Comment: It looks like a deadlock in getSessionToken()

Comment: @teepee SONY it is a deadlock, unfortunately the API code is not public, so I cannot understand why it happens. I'm not calling getSessionToken in any part of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I was using Parse Android SDK v1.7.1 which has a bug. This bug causes deadlock and conseguently the UI blocks and generates ANR. The new version 1.8.0 has fix the bug.